# Jack the ripper zip password cracking process - unshadow

Tags: password-protection, cracking

Anyone know the usage/commands for zip2john/rar2john. I have the bleeding-jumbo version of John the ripper installed. I have a my password locked zip file (*file.zip*) and a unzipped word list (*Rocktastic12a*).

Im trying to understand the process (not sure if im right?):

Create (parse) a hash file from the zip file:

```
zip2john /root/Downloads/file.zip > /root/hash.txt
```

Read the contents of the hash.txt file

```
cat /root/hash.txt
```

Crack the password

```
john --wordlist=/media/root/Gen\ Shiz/Rocktastic12a /root/hash.txt
```

**Now here's where i get an error**

```
Using default input encoding: UTF-8
No passwords hashes loaded (see FAQ)
```

Ive read about using an 'unshadow' command but im not sure what it is or how this works. Does it convert the hash or wordlist to a unix command and write something to a Kali file somewhere?

How do i get my hashes loaded?

Id really like to know the next step so i can get the full process (or the last command(s)) - can anyone help please?

p.s Ive also tried:

`john --format=zip /media/root/Gen\ Shiz/Rocktastic12a /root/hash.txt`

but i get

`Warning: invalid UTF-8 seen reading /media/root/Gen\ Shiz/Rocktastic12a`

Thanks

Comment: This is hardly a programming question.

Comment: isnt entering commands into a computer to get something done 'computer programming'?. Sorry if the question wasnt as highbrow as you'd like but the answer really helped me get on with my systems security studies.

Comment: No, actually it isn't. The command line and tools thereunder are more of a topic for [su]. If your "commands you enter into a computer" is in terms of programming languages or programming tools, then this is the site for the question but general purpose programs that aren't related to programming is off-topic.

Comment: ok thanks for the help - i didnt even know the site existed. Will use in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before shadow, the password hash was stored in /etc/passwd.  With unshadow, you can create a password file in that old format, which is what john needs.

```
unshadow /etc/passwd /etc/shadow > /tmp/passwd_unsh.txt
```

Now you can use /tmp/passwd_unsh.txt with john.
This information can be found in the doc folder.  You don't need unshadow for your excercise.
To specify the wordlist on the commandline:

```
john -wordlist=/media/root/Gen\ Shiz/Rocktastic12a /root/hash.txt
```

Comment: Correct Process:

zip2john /root/Downloads/file.zip > /root/hash.txt

unshadow /etc/passwd /etc/shadow > /tmp/passwd_unsh.txt

cat /root/hash.txt

john --wordlist=/media/root/Gen\ Shiz/Rocktastic12a /tmp/passwd_unsh.txt

renaming passwd_unsh.txt with every new hash created or zip file needing to be cracked?

Comment: do i even need to use this commend in the process: cat /root/hash.txt

Comment: only if you want to have a look at the contents

Comment: many thanks for you help. Your explanation really provided the missing link to something i was stuck on for a few days and gave me a better understanding of hashing. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try installing john-jumbo instead of john.

Mac users with Homebrew:

```
brew uninstall john
brew install john-jumbo
```